# C++ data lost after function call

Tags: c++, function, memory, vector

I guess it is something very trivial, but I'm stuck and can't find what's wrong with this:

```
std::vector<const char*> getExtensions()
{
    std::vector<const char*> extensions;

    // let's get a list of available extensions from Vulkan
    uint32_t availableExtensionCount = 0;
    vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &availableExtensionCount, nullptr);

    std::vector<VkExtensionProperties> availableExtensions(availableExtensionCount);
    vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &availableExtensionCount, availableExtensions.data());

    for (const VkExtensionProperties& extension : availableExtensions)
    {
        extensions.push_back(extension.extensionName);
    }

    return extensions;
}
```

So if I call it from here:

```
bool checkSupportedExtensions(const std::vector<const char*> extensions)
{
    // make sure that we support all requested extensions
    bool found;

    for (const auto& availableExtenstion : getExtensions())
    {
```

availableExtenstion  is full of gibberish.

I'm guessing that in the getExtensions function I'm inserting char* which get's deleted as soon as the function is executed, right? If that's the case, how to keep the string in vector?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of `char *`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a vector of pointers that indirects to deleted variables.

You should use a std::string instead:

```
std::vector<std::string> getExtensions()
{
    std::vector<std::string> extensions;

    // let's get a list of available extensions from Vulkan
    uint32_t availableExtensionCount = 0;
    vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &availableExtensionCount, nullptr);

    std::vector<VkExtensionProperties> availableExtensions(availableExtensionCount);
    vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &availableExtensionCount, availableExtensions.data());

    for (const VkExtensionProperties& extension : availableExtensions)
    {
        extensions.push_back(std::string(extension.extensionName));
    }

    return extensions;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try use vector of strings instead `std::vector<std::string>`. Just try

`...
        extensions.push_back(std::string(extension.extensionName));
...`

and see if it works.
Also you can print out the extensions before pushing them back to the vector and see if they are meaningful strings.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of issues in your code.

First, you are storing pointers to char in your vector. You have no control over what happens to the memory that the pointers in your vector refer to.

Try

```
  std::vector<std:string> extensions;
```

Second, while it is not an error, it is not a good idea to return large data structures by value because you can get massive copying.

Comment: Yup, I agree with you on following the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about the data being lost as `availableExtensions`, which contains the actual data gets deleted (due to out of scope) as soon as the function `getExtensions()` returns to the caller.

What you need is copying the `extension.extensionName` data from the local stack to the heap, so that it lives as long as you are maintaining the `vector` returned by the `getExtensions()`. However, it also means you are also responsible to release/delete it when you are done using it, which makes the thing little bit difficult.

The simple solution to your code is to user the `std::string` which essentially does the same thing for you. Hence the only thing you need to do is change the vector definition from `std::vector<const char*>` to `std::vector<std::string>`

If you are looking for the much efficient solution, use the vector of `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>` with the following change when inserting the data to the vector

`extensions.push_back(std::make_unique<std::string>(extension.extensionName));`